# Cannot connect to Oracle Database via TIBCO BW

Tags: java, oracle, tibco, tibco-business-works

I recently started working with TIBCO and creating a process as follows.

1. Read data from a Oracle database.
2. Creating CSV file.
3. Place the file in FTP server.

I have setup `oracle 21c XE` database in my computer and created a FTP sever. I was able to connect to FTP Server, however, facing issues with connecting to oracle database.

First, I received `Failed to find or load the JDBC driver` error when I configured `JDBC Connection`. After doing some research, I got to know that `ojdbc` is not packaged with TIBCO. Then I downloaded `ojdbc11.jar` and placed that in `TIBCO_HOME/tcpl/5.11/jdbc/` directory.

Now, I do not get the previous error, but when I validate the project I could see following error.
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.plugin.jdbc.JDBCCommon`

**Version Info**

- Oracle DB: 21c
- TIBCO TRA: 5.11
- TIBCO BW: 5.14

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did to install the ORACLE JDBC driver is valid but you need to use a driver version for Java 8 while BW 5.14 is using Java 8 (the name should be ojdbc8.jar).

Note also that ORACLE 21c is not officially supported by BW 5.14.

I would test the following options :

1. Download ojdbc8.jar for ORACLE 21c (if it exist) and test with this version
2. Download ojdbc8.jar for ORACLE 19c, this should work (provided that ORACLE 21c should support connection from client applications using older driver version)